# Spree demo missing product images

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, spree

I followed the instructions on http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html
Additionally, I followed instructions on http://codeofalice.com/code/installing-rmagick-on-windows-7/ to install imagemagick and rmagick gems.  No errors reported.

When I run `identify` I get

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-8 2012-06-20 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Usage: identify.exe [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ... ]

Image Settings:
  -alpha option        on, activate, off, deactivate, set, opaque, copy
                       transparent, extract, background, or shape
  -antialias           remove pixel-aliasing
```

The demo site runs, but the images are missing.  Additionally, I can't  upload images (no errors) - they just don't upload.  I believe it is something related to ImageMagick, but am not sure.

Comment: When you run `identify` without any arguments it shows you the help file on how to use it.

Comment: But why aren't there any images?  Not sure if it is a Spree Issue, ImageMagick Issue, or something else.

Comment: @Justjoehere Can you show your gemfile/gemfile.lock? What command are you using to generate the demo? What's the output of that command.

Comment: I ran [code]bundle exec rake spree_sample:load[/code]

Comment: I received I received 'create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css
      create  app/overrides
      append  db/seeds.rb
     copying  migrations
    creating  database
     running  migrations
     loading  seed data
     loading  sample data
      insert  config/routes.rb
**************************************************
We added the following line to your application's config/routes.rb file:

    mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
**************************************************
Spree has been installed successfully. You're all ready to go!

Enjoy!'

Comment: Gemlock file is at https://gist.github.com/justjoehere/b5ff91b865808614c17e

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle exec rake spree_sample:load` It worked for me!